# Examine if the set of elements are linearly dependant.

Tags: linear-algebra

> We have that $S=\{1+t^3,3+t-2t^2,-t+3t^2-t^3\}$.
>
> a) Is $S$ linearly dependant in $P_3$?
>
> b) Can the $S$ be a basis for $P_3$?

**a)** The basis for $P_3$ are $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}.$ The definition of linearly dependant is that I should be able to write one of the elements as a linear combination of the others. It seems as if I combine any two elements in $S$, I can get the third, since any two of them contain all the basis vectors.

The answer is however that they are linearly independant. Why?

**b)** Since there are only $3$ elements, they can never be a base in a space of dimension $4$, since $\dim(P_3)=4.$  Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct for part $b$ (well, I think you mean to say that $\dim P_3=4$.) For part $a$, I can't follow your reasoning.  If you can, in fact, express the first, say, of the elements of $S$ as a combination of the second two then you have proven linear dependence.  But can you?

Comment: solve the equation System
$$\alpha(1+t^3)+\beta(3+t-2t^2)+\gamma(-t+3t^2-t^3)=0$$

Comment: Consider the polynomials $p(x) = 1 + t + t^2 + t^3$ and $q(x) = 1$ to see why your reasoning is flawed for part $a$. Together, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ contain all the basis vectors, but you certainly cannot write any polynomial in $P_3$ as a linear combination of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$

Comment: @lulu - That is the million dollar question. How Can I find it out?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - For what variables?

Comment: @jacer21 - In order to motivate or show by counter-example that I can't write any polynomial in $P_3$ as a L.C of $1(x)$ and $p(x)$ could one take as example the following polynomial: $t^3$? Because no matter how I add $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ I'll always have a $t^2$ and $t$ term to bother me?

Comment: Well, what is stopping you from trying?  A linear dependence would have the form $0=a(1+t^3)+b(3+t-2t^2)+c(-t+3t^2-t^3)$  Write that as a cubic and solve for $a,b,c$.

Comment: @Parseval That's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $$\alpha(1+t^3)+\beta(3+t-2t^2)+\gamma(-t+3t^2-t^3)=0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$

and you wish to prove $\alpha= \beta =\gamma = 0$.

Plugging in $t = -1$ gives

$$5\gamma = 0 \implies \gamma = 0$$

Now we have $\alpha(1+t^3)+\beta(3+t-2t^2) = 0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Plugging in $t = \frac32$ gives

$$\frac{35}{8}\alpha = 0 \implies \alpha = 0$$

Now we have $\beta(3+t-2t^2) = 0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Plugging in $t = 1$ gives

$$2\beta = 0 \implies \beta = 0$$

Hence $\alpha =  \beta = \gamma = 0$ so $\{1+t^3,3+t-2t^2,-t+3t^2-t^3\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: But If I can just choose to plug in any value of $t$ then I can choose a root for each parenthesis? This doesn't make sense to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Parseval Yes, you can plug in any $t \in \mathbb{R}$. If you choose a root for a certain parenthesis, then that coefficient disappears from the expression so it can be useful sometimes. Alternative method would be to group the coefficients under common powers of $t$:
$$0 = \alpha(1+t^3)+\beta(3+t-2t^2)+\gamma(-t+3t^2-t^3) = (\alpha + 3\beta) + (\beta - \gamma)t + (-2\beta + 3\gamma)t^2 + (\alpha - \gamma)t^3$$
Now it has to be $\alpha + 3\beta = 0$, $\beta - \gamma = 0$, $-2\beta + 3\gamma = 0$ and $\alpha - \gamma = 0$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot!